# How to decode symbol &#39; in Android's WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to display the following html code in a WebView:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body> <p> c&#39;est la vie</p> </body>
</html>
```

The symbol ' is encoded as &#39;

I call this method to load the html is a WebView:

```
webview.loadData(contentText, "text/html", null);
```

For some reason, the WebView displays:

> c&

instead of :

> c'est la vie

Do you know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
String unencodedHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body> <p> c&#39;est la vie</p> </body></html>";
String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(unencodedHtml.getBytes(),
    Base64.NO_PADDING);
myWebView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
```

for more info, read the official guide about [Building web apps in WebView](http://mWebView.setWebViewClient(new%20HelloWebViewClient());)

Answer (score 0):

What is inside contentText?

```
    val content:String = "this is a test with ' in the text"
    wv.loadData(content, "text/html", null)
```

works perfectly.

Comment: Indeed, but in my source String, the symbol ' is encoded as &#39;

Comment: i just can't reproduce your problem! but maybe you are using a font that messes with your result? Or are there some other settings on your webview that could produce this. Or maybe the contentText is set from a source that also did some encoding?

Comment: Does your String include &#39; instead of ' ?

Comment: Yes, tried all kinds of formats.
    
        `val content ="<!DOCTYPE html><html><body> <p> c&#39;est la vie test'test</p> </body></html>"
        wv.loadData(content, "text/html", null)`

Comment: Anyway... Kevin's answer fixed my problem :) Thanks !